# Receiving Undefined Error for Javascript Program when Updating for CRUD Frontend

Tags: javascript, html, api

I created a frontend javascript for my ruby on rails backend and I am receiving the following error when I try to update a book title:

Error: app.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderUpdateForm' of undefined
at App.handleEditClick (app.js:65)

I am receiving books titles and their authors from a backend api.

Here is the code:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const app = new App();
  app.attachEventListeners();
  app.adapter.fetchAuthors().then(app.createAuthors);
  app.adapter.fetchBooks().then(app.createBooks);

});
```

```
    class Book {
  constructor(data) {
    this.id = data.id;
    this.title = data.title;
    const author = Author.findById(data.author_id);
    this.author = author.name;
    Book.all.push(this);
  }

  update({ title }) {
    this.title = title;
  }


  renderListItem() {
    return `
    <li>
      <h3>${this.title} - ${this.author}
      <button data-id=${this.id}>update</button>
        <button data-id=${this.id}>delete</button>
      </h3>
    </li>`;
  }

  renderUpdateForm() {
    return `
    <form data-id='${this.id}'>
      <label>Title</label>
      <p>
        <input type="text" value="${this.title}" />
      </p>

      <button type='submit'>Save Book</button>
    </form>
  `;
  }

  static findById(id) {
    return this.all.find(book => book.id === id);
  }
}

Book.all = [];
```

```
    class App {
  constructor() {
    this.adapter = new Adapter();

    this.handleEditClick = this.handleEditClick.bind(this);
    this.handleEditClick = this.handleDeleteClick.bind(this);
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.createBooks = this.createBooks.bind(this);
    this.createAuthors = this.createAuthors.bind(this);
    this.addBooks = this.addBooks.bind(this);

  }

  attachEventListeners() {
    $('#books-list').on('click', 'button', this.handleEditClick);
    $('#books-list').on('click', 'button', this.handleDeleteClick);
    $('#update').on('submit', 'form', this.handleFormSubmit);
  }

  createBooks(books) {
    books.forEach(book => {
      new Book(book);
    });
    console.log(this);
    this.addBooks();
  }

  createAuthors(authors) {
    authors.forEach(author => {
      new Author(author);
    });
    console.log(this);
    this.addAuthors();
  }

  addBooks() {
    $('#books-list').empty();
    Book.all.forEach(book => $('#books-list').append(book.renderListItem()));
  }

  addAuthors() {
    $('#authors-list').empty();
    Author.all.forEach(author => $('#authors-list').append(author.renderListItem()));
  }


  handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const id = e.target.dataset.id;
    const book = Book.findById(id);
    const title = $(e.target)
      .find('input')
      .val();

    const bodyJSON = { title };
    this.adapter.updateBook(book.id, bodyJSON).then(updatedBook => {
      const book = Book.findById(updatedBook.id);
      book.update(updatedBook);
      this.addBooks();
    });
  }

  handleEditClick(e) {
    const id = e.target.dataset.id;
    const book = Book.findById(id);
    $('#update').html(book.renderUpdateForm());
  }

  handleDeleteClick(e) {
    const id = e.target.dataset.id;
    const book = Book.findById(id);
    const title = $(e.target)
      .find('input')
      .val();

    const bodyJSON = { title };
    this.adapter.deleteBook(book.id, bodyJSON);

  }


}
```

```
 class Adapter {
  constructor() {
    this.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1';
    this.headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json'
    };
  }

  fetchBooks() {
    return this.get(`${this.baseUrl}/books`);
  }

  fetchAuthors() {
    return this.get(`${this.baseUrl}/authors`);
  }

  updateBook(id, body) {
    return this.patch(`${this.baseUrl}/books/${id}`, body);
  }

  deleteBook(id, body) {
    return this.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/books/${id}`, body);
  }

  get(url) {
    return fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
  }

  patch(url, body) {
    return fetch(url, {
      method: 'PATCH',
      headers: this.headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(res => res.json());
  }

  delete(url, body) {
    return fetch(url, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: this.headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const book = Book.findById(id);
```

returns `undefined`.

Which means there is no entry with that `id`. `e.target.dataset.id` probably has a different value than expected (`console.log` is your friend).

---

To guard against this type of error (so your app doesn't break when you're using an invalid/non-existent `id`), you could just wrap next line in a condition:

```
handleEditClick(e) {
  const id = e.target.dataset.id;
  const book = Book.findById(id);
  if (book) {
     $('#update').html(book.renderUpdateForm());
  }
}
```

Better checks are whether the result has a function named `renderUpdateForm`:

```
if (book && typeof book.renderUpdateForm === 'function') { 
  $('#update').html(book.renderUpdateForm())
}
```

or if it is a Book instance:

```
if (book instanceof Book) { 
  $('#update').html(book.renderUpdateForm())
}
```

Comment: Tao - Thanks for your help so far.  Do you know why the book would not be an instance of the object?  I used console.log to ensure that the ID was not nil.  The ID is correct, but the const book is not receiving an instance of the object.  Thanks.

Comment: `findById` seems to do a strict comparison: `return this.all.find(book => book.id === id);`. Are you sure `typeof id` is the same? As in `0 !== '0'` (number `0` is not strictly equal to string `'0'`). If you're expecting numbers in `findById`, you might want to cast the `id` as number: `return this.find(book => book.id === +id)`. If you're expecting strings, cast as string: `return this.find(book => book.id === '' + id)`.

Comment: @Carla, another option is to use loose comparison `return this.all.find(book => book.id == id);`, but I strongly advise against it, as it can produce unpredictable results. In principle, you want to exclude loose comparisons from your code. You'll always come back to them sooner or later and it will be after a lot of hours spent trying to debug some side effect. Also, on perfectly valid grounds, experienced developers will dismiss/under-evaluate your code for using loose comparisons.